# Transparent Select Dropdown Menu only in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a SELECT element with a custom styling. I use a background image containing a "dropdown-arrow". You can find an example of what I'm doing in this liveweave http://liveweave.com/xcfh0Z

When you use the select box in Chrome, Safari, IE or Opera, everything works like expected: The select is displayed with the given image, and if I click on the select box, I can see a dropdown list with white background.

However, Firefox behaves different. When I click on the select box in Firefox, it opens a dropdown list with a transparent background. The only way I found to come around this issue is to use a

```
background-color: white
```

... which causes a "not so cool white border" around my select.

Has anyone an idea of how to come along this issue?

Comment: Maybe you can make it with JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for your background image to work, the `background-color` of your `<select>` has to be transparent. Instead you should set the `<option>` background to white, like this:

```css
option {
    background-color: white;
}
```

See [DEMO](http://liveweave.com/BMtlXc).